# ReferenceError: $ionicUser is not defined when use ionic-push

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to test ionic-push, so I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-from-scratch).

But, when I add a button and add code to DashCtrl. After that, re-run `ionic-serve --lab`. Click button it make error like this:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't post screen shots of the console.. post the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the $ionicUser service into your controller like this:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicUser, $ionicPush) {
})
```

If this does not work, then update your ionic CLI tool and try again. There is no need to manually include .js file.